# Emoji cStringUsingEncoding with NSASCIIStringEncoding not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, emoji

I have an array with data :

```
MY_ARRAY: (
  "email="My_Email_ID"",
  "message=\Ud83d\Ude0a",
  "key="MY_KEY"
  "id="MY_ID""
)
```

In the message field I have added emoji and it is showing it's hex value.

But when I try converting it to string :

```
string = [MY_ARRAY componentsJoinedByString: @"&"];
```

the output in terminal shows:

```
email="My_Email_ID"&message=&key="MY_KEY"&id="MY_ID"
```

why is it converting back to emoji?

The problem which I am facing is at this line:

```
const char *charData = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

as I am getting null here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing below line:

```
const char *charData = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

to

```
const char *charData = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

solved my issue.

Thanks to this [forum](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/utf8string-vs-nsasciistringencoding.1663883/).

> If at all possible, stay away from anything other than UTF8. 
>   NSASCIIStringEncoding will break (return NULL) whenever there is a non-ASCII character in the string. There is no reason to take the risk. Only use cStringUsingEncoding: if you actually for whatever strange reason need a string in that particular encoding. Since NSLog expects UTF8 strings, any encoding that isn't a subset of UTF8 will produce strange results.